# Python 3 execute a file in another window

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

My problem is that im trying too use

```
def openFile():
os.system("yth.exe checks.asc")
```

this to open the file with that exe file.

My problem is that i want it to run in a second window and everytime i start is it overwrites its. And styes in the same cmd window. I tried googling and trying for like 3h now and i dont found anything. Mybay you guys can help me. I want that the yth.exe runs the checks.asc in a separate spawns window and not overwriting the "main program" window.

Comment: `subprocess.call('yth.exe checks.asc', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)`. See the docs for [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: Ok if tried it and its working but its pauses the rest of the script. Any solutions for that ?

Comment: Never mind, It's working thx for the holy question master. But can u run it in the background and not having it to pop up ?

Comment: The following startup info will create the window minimized: `SW_MINIMIZE = 6;` `si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO();` `si.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;` `si.wShowWindow = SW_MINIMIZE`. Then to create the process without waiting for it to exit, use `p = subprocess.Popen('yth.exe checks.asc', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, startupinfo=si)`. You can call `p.poll()` to see if it's still running or `p.terminate()` to kill it, or wait for it to exit via `p.wait()`.

Comment: Thx for that answer, i got it now its very nice to understand subprocess a bit and work with it also.

Answer (score 0):

Check file python.exe to ensure it's not being run in Compatibility Mode or "Run this program as an administrator."  Some of these options make it necessary for windows to run in a separate window.